# ASP.net web api proxy all not found requests

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to build my own javascript front end that may in the future replace an existing front end.  My javascript ajax requests should all make requests to the server as if the javascript is hosted on the same server.  For example

```
$.ajax({
  url: "api/test",
}).done(function() {
});
```

instead of

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.otherdomain.com/api/test",
}).done(function() {
});
```

How can I create an asp.net web api route that proxies all requests that don't match any routes or resources on a local server and instead route them to http://www.otherdomain.com

Comment: I Googled "JQuery Ajax Relative Path" and got an answer immediately.

Comment: I don't want to do this at all in my javascript.  I want the server to take care of the routing.

Comment: How do you expect the server to fix your URL before actually receiving it? The only place you can do this is on the client!

Comment: I want my ajax to make the call "api/test" request to my asp.net server.  My backend doesn't find "api/test" so then the server goes and tries "http://www.otherdomain.com/api/test".  It finds the result on the server and returns the result to the original "api/test" javascript ajax request.